# How to split dataframe into smaller dataframe

Tags: r, split

I am using split function to split a large data frame into smaller data frames.

I've tried two codes:

```
split(largedata, largedata$year)
year <- split(largedata, largedata$year)
```

I don't know why it doesn't save smaller data frames in my environment. It just shows up on my console but it's not what I expected.

I expected to see year2000, year2001, year2002 data frames in my global environment. If you have any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you think `split()` assigns its result to an environment?  Did you read `help(split)`?  It outputs a list.

Comment: I see... I just saw someone's post that the opposite of `rbind()` is `split()` function so I assumed this will do the opposite and spit out data frames. Would you use subset function instead?

Comment: I think it's best to keep similar data in a list, so I would just rename the list elements with `names(year) <- paste0("year", names(year))`.  Then you can call its elements with `year$year2001`, etc.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean..